# Why my program doesn't allow me to input b?

Tags: c, printf, scanf, codeblocks, gets

I want to input valors for a and b, being a an int and b a str. When I run my program I can input a valor, but then it ingnores printf() and gets() for b.

```
#include<stdio.h>>
int main()
{
    int a;
    char b[5];
    printf("Write a:\n");
    scanf("%i", &a);
    printf("Write b:\n");
    gets(b);
    printf("a = %i, b = %s", a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

In the end, it just prints:

```
a = (valor written), b =
```

I don't know what's wrong with this, neither if it's a different way to get this working. I'm pretty new with C. Thank you in advance. ;)

Comment: Better to use `fgets(b, sizeof b, stdin);`.  Keep in mind that with user input you may have to content with the newline, and don't forget to allow room for the null terminator in your buffer.  As is you only have room for 3 characters of user input.

Comment: Suggested read: [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used)

Comment: `gets` was removed from `C11`, so that could be causing some confusion in your validator.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [scanf() leaves the newline character in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-newline-character-in-the-buffer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `gets` is unsafe and is not supported by the C Standard. Instead use either `scanf` or `fgets`.

As for your problem then after this call of `scanf`

```
scanf("%i", &a);
```

the input buffer contains the new line character `'\n'` that corresponds to the pressed key Enter. And the following call of `gets` reads an empty string by encountering the new line character.

Instead of using `gets` write

```
scanf( " %4[^\n]", b );
```

Pay attention to the leading space in the format string. It allows to skip white space characters as for example the new line character `'\n'`. And the call of `scanf` can read a string with maximum length equal to 4.  If you want to read a larger string then enlarge the array `b` and the field width specifier in the format string.

Comment: +1 for providing yet another great example of why `scanf()` should never be preferred over eg. `fgets()` when performing user input tasks.   The rules to use `scanf` correctly are varied, complicated and error prone.

Comment: This was giving me headaches for days.
Thank you very much. That done it.